# Sandcastle Help Builder - SandcastleBuilder.Components.ShowMissingComponent' was not found

Tags: .net, sandcastle

NOTE: Posted on Sandcastle Help Builder website as well.

I got this error:

> BUILDASSEMBLER : error :
>   BuildAssembler: The type
>   'SandcastleBuilder.Components.ShowMissingComponent'
>   was not found in the component
>   assembly 'C:\Program
>   Files\EWSoftware\Sandcastle Help File
>   Builder

I checked (vis Reflector); it's there.
Uninstalled and reinstalled:

- Sandcastle (Version 2.6.1062.1)
- Help File Builder (1.8.0.3 Release)
- VS 2008 SDK 1.1

Still getting error.
Note this warning in the log:
SHFB: Warning BE0004: MRefBuilder has a version of '2.6.10621.1' but version '2.4.10520.1' was expected. You may need to update your copy of the help file builder.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks,
BP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too got the same problem.

Solved it by installing an older version of sandcastle(2.4.10520.1). 
You can download the older version from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=e82ea71d-da89-42ee-a715-696e3a4873b2&displaylang=en